# Additional save button on Django admin pages with extra functionality

Tags: django, django-admin

How can you add an additional Save-button on admin list view pages, like shown on the image, that saves the changes but also does something extra before or afterwards? In my case, I need to export the changes to an external database.

I know that it possible to achieve this functionality via "actions" but it is cumbersome to select the correct action from select-box, when you need to do it repetitively over and over again.

It would be beneficial to be able to add extra save button both to the list view and the change view.

[image: Example af a list view page with an extra save button]

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of digging and came up with a solution that is as ugly as hell. I wish there was easier and more elegant way to do this. In my opinion, there should be a feature in ModelAdmin for having an extra button like this.

(This only works in list view)

You need to overwrite the pagination.html admin template and add the extra save button:

```
{% load admin_list %}
{% load i18n %}
<p class="paginator">
{% if pagination_required %}
{% for i in page_range %}
    {% paginator_number cl i %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{{ cl.result_count }} {% if cl.result_count == 1 %}{{ cl.opts.verbose_name }}{% else %}{{ cl.opts.verbose_name_plural }}{% endif %}
{% if show_all_url %}<a href="{{ show_all_url }}" class="showall">{% translate 'Show all' %}</a>{% endif %}
{% if cl.formset and cl.result_count %}
    <input type="submit" name="_save" class="default" value="{% translate 'Save' %}">
    <input type="submit" name="_save" class="default" value="{% translate 'Save & export' %}" style="margin-right: 1em">{% endif %}
</p>
```

Then add code like this to your `admin.ModelAdmin` class:

```
    # ------------------
    # Ugly hack to be able to add extra "Save & export" button to list
    # To understand take a look at the source code, changelist_view() in options.py, look for the comment:
    #   "Handle POSTed bulk-edit data."
    # ------------------

    _places_to_be_exported = []

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        # needs to be the same text as on that extra save-button
        if form.data['_save'] == 'Save & export':
            self._places_to_be_exported_to_es.append(obj.id)

    def message_user(self, request, message, level=messages.INFO, extra_tags="", fail_silently=False):
        super().message_user(request, message, level, extra_tags, fail_silently)
        if self._places_to_be_exported_to_es:
            queryset = PlaceName.objects.filter(id__in=self._places_to_be_exported)
            self._places_to_be_exported = []
            self._do_what_ever_you_need_to_do(queryset)

    # ------------------
    # End of this ugly hack
    # ------------------
```